# Cookie not getting deleted by remove('cookie_name') and removeAll() in ngx-cookie

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Unable to delete cookie(using ngx-cookie). To set cookie I am using:

```
setCookie(cookie: string) {
this.cookieService.put('userDetails', JSON.stringify(cookie), { domain: 
'localhost' });
}
```

It is still showing the cookie in application tab. And after remove() also the cookie details is getting printed.

```
logout() {
this.securityService.setLoginStatus(false);
console.log('cookie details before: ' + JSON.stringify(this.cookie));
this.socketService.logout(JSON.parse(this.cookie).id);
this.cookieService.remove('userDetails', { domain: 'localhost' });
console.log('cookie details after: ' + JSON.stringify(this.cookie));
}
```

Is there any mistake I am doing here or how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: what code you have written in this.cookieService.remove() method ?

Comment: I have not written this method. I am using CookieService from ngx-cookie and injecting it where ever I want to use. So, by using cookieService object, I am accessing the remove(cookie_name, cookie_options). Here is the link which I had followed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie

Answer (score 0):

As of today, in the latest version of (16.0.1), ngx-cookie-services defines the delete function (in Readme.MD) as follows:

```
delete( name: string, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean, sameSite: 'Lax' | 'None' | 'Strict' = 'Lax'): void;
```

Most of the time supplying only cookie name and domain name is not enough. So, rather than,

```
this.cookieService.remove('userDetails', { domain: 'localhost' });
```

the code below should work:

```
this.cookieService.delete('userDetails', '/', 'localhost', false, 'Lax')
```

There are several good practices mentioned in the document. If it still doesn't work the problem might be related with server side settings like regeneration of the cookie etc.